# Floating point precision issue in PHP and MySQL for storing occasional decimal values

Tags: php, mysql, floating-point, floating-point-precision, decimal-point

I want to store occasional decimal values in my MySQL database and display them in my PHP application. Let me explain, what do I mean by occasional decimal values. The numbers are whole numbers at most of the time like an integer. For example, 160 or 170 etc.. But sometimes I need to save values like 98.6.

First I used `DECIMAL(4,1)` datatype in the database and I found that I alway get numbers like this: 160.0, 170.0 and 98.6 etc.. So, I changed it to `FLOAT`. On my local environment, I see the numbers as 160, 170, 98.6 etc. on both the PHP application and phpMyAdmin. But on my production environment, I see those numbers like 160, 170, 98.6 etc. on phpMyAdmin. But on PHP application, I see the numbers like 160, 170, 98.599998474121 etc..

Now I need to decide whether switch back to `decimal` or keep using `float`. And either way, I need to find a solution to convert the numbers to the format like this: 160, 170 and 98.6 etc..

What do you think is better for this purpose: `decimal` or `float`? What is the best way to convert the numbers to whole numbers if the fractional part of the number is zero (while using `decimal`)? What is the best way to convert float values like 98.599998474121 to 98.6?

Converting the numbers to whole numbers if the fractional part of the number is zero:

```
<?php
if (fmod($number, 1) == 0) {
    $number = intval($number)
}
```

Is there any better way?

Comment: Use float datatype in mysql , and in PHP while saving use : `$foo = "105";
echo number_format((float)$foo, 2, '.', '');  // Outputs -> 105.00`

Comment: FLOAT(1) seems like the way to go, right?

Comment: @Strawberry, did you mean the FLOAT(1) as a link? PHP or mysql related? An 'internet search' wasn't specific. I misunderstand your point - just confused.

Comment: I mean use a FLOAT(1) data type in MySQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Understand that float is not a precise decimal number but a value that's close to it. The way it's stored is very efficient at the cost of not being exact. Without knowing your exact needs, one possible solution is to store the numbers as floats and round them to one decimal.

```
// the casts are there just for the demonstration, you probably don't need them
$number = "170";
echo round((float)$number, 1); // gives 170
$number = "98.6";
echo round((float)$number, 1); // gives 98.6
```

Floats represent integers the way you want them, and they lose precision only when you store certain decimals.

Comment: I did not know that `round` removes decimal digits if they are zero. This works good with `decimal` datatype.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this error as well. (Read this http://www.leaseweblabs.com/2013/06/the-php-floating-point-precision-is-wrong-by-default/ )

It is a php related error.

If you know for sure that your fractional part has a maximum of one digit and you encounter more, you know you need to re-process the number

You can get the precision like so:

```
function precision($num) { 
   return strlen(substr($num, strpos($num, '.')+1)); 
}
```

Comment: I don't think it's a good solution to get the substring, as 98.599998474121 will become 98.5 instead 98.6.

Comment: I also tried to change `precision` in `php.ini`, but this also did not work.

Comment: You do realize that the function I suggested returns the length, not the substring, right? That purely counts the number of digits after the '.' .

Comment: That function only helps you identify the cases in which the float error appears

Comment: Sorry, I missed that. Anyways, that is not a complete solution.

Comment: Besides detecting the issue, I saw no need for another solution, since your 'round' call does exactly that. Anyway, hope this may come in handy some day.